# The conversion is not supported. [ Type to convert from (if known) = nvarchar, Type to convert to (if known) = image ]

Tags: c#, .net, windows, sql-server-ce

i have one windows form . in that form when i update an image it show me this message :
"The conversion is not supported. [ Type to convert from (if known) = nvarchar, Type to convert to (if known) = image ]"..in database the datatype is image..

this is my code :
please give me a solution...

```
                ms = new MemoryStream();
                pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                photo_aray = new byte[ms.Length];
                ms.Position = 0;
                ms.Read(photo_aray, 0, photo_aray.Length);



                cmd = new SqlCeCommand("update register set name='" + textBox1.Text + "' ,address='" + textBox2.Text + "',mobile='" + textBox3.Text + "',gender='" + a + "',dob='" + textBox4.Text + "' ,photo='"+byteArrayToImage(photo_aray)+"',worktype='" + comboBox2.SelectedItem + "',workertype='" + comboBox1.SelectedItem + "',dor='" + textBox5.Text+ "' where name='" + comboBox3.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'", con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();




    //convert bytearray to image...
    public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
        Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
        return returnImage;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you want to use a parameterized query http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlcecommand.parameters(v=vs.100).aspx

Second, the "image" type in the database just means "binary data" it is not the same as the Image class in .NET.  You want to pass the byte array itself, not the Image that your byteArrayToImage() returns.

Comment: thanks ...it has been resolved by your suggestion..thanks once again..but still i have one problem : i deploy my application and my connection string is :   SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\ \sailesh\Desktop\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");

Comment: but when i run setup on another pc after deploying..it show me this error : "An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Users\vivek.nuna\Documents\VisualStudio2005\Projects\SubsystemSyncService\TestClient\bin\Debug\aspnetdb.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share." ..please give me solution ..its very important

Comment: I don't have enough information. But the error message should give you what you need to track it down yourself.